# Java/javaFX: new connection to db for every query?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, javafx, database-connection

So, I am creating an application in javaFX (for learning purposes only) which mainly consists of a tabpane with sub-fxmls for each tab. Each tab consist of a tableview with data collected from a database. To connect to the database I have a separate connection class that creates a new connection pool using c3p0.

My first question is: Should I create (and close) a new connection for every query I make to the database?

Example: upon entering a new tab I create a new connection, collect the data and then close the connection (with statement and resultset).

If not, how would I do this in a proper and efficient way?

My second question: Currently my application is doing what's described above, but I notice that if I leave the application open for a while, without interacting with it, whenever I start interacting with it again it freezes for a bit before it continues. The current table that is viewed at that time then shows "no data in table", until I switch to another tab and then the data is displayed properly again. Why does this happen?

I am quite new to Java in general, and I couldn't find anything by searching that resembled my problem. My database is a postgres db.

**EDIT 1:**
Regarding question 2:
I have followed the mvc-pattern for this, not sure if that's a good idea, but that's another question.

There are four classes that play a part in a table's creation, which are:

Controller class:

```
public class StockController {

//tableview from fxml-file
@FXML
private TableView<List<Object>> stockTable;

//
private BuildDataModel stockData = new BuildDataModel();

//Called from main whenever currently active tab changes to this tab.
public void CreateView(){
    String query = "SELECT component.name, stock.* FROM component NATURAL JOIN stock";

    stockData.BuildData(stockTable, query);

}
//Called from main whenever currently active tab changes to another tab.
public void DestroyView(){
    if(!stockTable.getColumns().isEmpty()) {
        stockData.DeleteData();
    }
}
}
```

Model class:

```
public class BuildDataModel {

private Connection conn;
@FXML
private TableView<List<Object>> tableview;

public TableData data;

private TableData getAllData(String query){
    List<List<Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        conn = PostgresConnection.CreateConnection();
        st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = st.executeQuery();

        //We create columns
        int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            String columnName = rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i);
            columnNames.add(columnName);
        }
        //We populate our tabledata object with the data
        while(rs.next()){
            List<Object> row = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++){
                row.add(rs.getObject(i));

            }
            data.add(row);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn, st, rs);

    }
    return new TableData(columnNames, data);
}
//Called from controller class, calls getAllData with the specified query
//and populates tableview based on this.
public void BuildData(TableView<List<Object>> tableview, String query) {
    this.tableview = tableview;
    try {
        data = getAllData(query);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < data.getNumColumns(); i++) {
            TableColumn<List<Object>, Object> column = new TableColumn<>(data.getColumnName(i));
            int columnIndex = i;
            column.setCellValueFactory(cellData ->
                    new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellData.getValue().get(columnIndex)));
            tableview.getColumns().add(column);
        }

        tableview.getItems().setAll(data.getData());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }

}

public void DeleteData(){
    tableview.getColumns().clear();
}}
```

Connection class:

```
public class PostgresConnection {

//DB credentials, modify as needed
private static final String HOST     = "localhost";
private static final String DATABASE = "<INSERT DATABASE HERE>";
private static final String USERNAME = "<INSERT USERNAME HERE>";
private static final String PASSWORD = "<INSERT PASSWORD HERE>";

//Default postgresql port, don't change unless you know what you're doing.
private static final String PORT     = "5432";
private static final String URL      = "jdbc:postgresql://" + HOST + ":" + PORT + "/" + DATABASE;
private static final String DRIVER_NAME = "org.postgresql.Driver";

private static Connection conn;

//Disables C3P0-pool logging
static {
    Properties p = new Properties(System.getProperties());
    p.put("com.mchange.v2.log.MLog", "com.mchange.v2.log.FallbackMLog");
    p.put("com.mchange.v2.log.FallbackMLog.DEFAULT_CUTOFF_LEVEL", "OFF");
    System.setProperties(p);
}

private static ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();

public static Connection CreateConnection() throws SQLException {
    try {
        cpds.setDriverClass(DRIVER_NAME);
    } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    cpds.setJdbcUrl(URL);
    cpds.setUser(USERNAME);
    cpds.setPassword(PASSWORD);
    cpds.setMinPoolSize(3);
    cpds.setAcquireIncrement(5);
    cpds.setMaxPoolSize(100);
    cpds.setMaxStatements(180);
    return cpds.getConnection();
}}
```

and DAO:

```
public class TableData {

private final List<String> columnNames;
private final List<List<Object>> data;

public TableData(List<String> columnNames, List<List<Object>> data) {
    this.columnNames = columnNames;
    this.data = data;
}

public int getNumColumns() {
    return columnNames.size();
}

public String getColumnName(int index) {
    return columnNames.get(index);
}

public int getNumRows() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getData(int column, int row) {
    return data.get(row).get(column);
}

public List<List<Object>> getData() {
    return data;
}
public void removeData(){
    data.clear();
    columnNames.clear();
}}
```

Comment: The short answer to your first question is:  Yes, create a new Connection each time.  There are ways to improve upon that (namely, a connection pool), but that is more advanced and not necessary in an initial design.  Your second question cannot be answered unless you add your code to your question.

Comment: Okay thanks, could you possibly elaborate on that? Regarding the second question, it seems to me like the connection times out or something, so that it struggles to regain it and therefore the application freezes. Considering the table shows no data after freeze, it would make sense from my perspective at least.

Comment: A connection pool is an object (which you normally should not attempt to write yourself) which maintains a handful of open Connections, and when an application asks for a “new” Connection, the pool returns one of the available already-open ones.  When the application closes the Connection, what actually happens is that it stays open but is returned the pool’s available set.  Usually a JDBC driver makes an implementation available as a [ConnectionPoolDataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/ConnectionPoolDataSource.html).

Comment: Okay, yea that makes sense. I should probably read up a bit more about connection pools. I added the code as requested.